# ComponentSearch with submit button

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

I need help in making the component search fire up only when a submit button is clicked or hit enter key. not as the user types.

I have set up my state and 
used onValueChange method to get the value entered
made the button

```
state={
        searchText: ""
    }
......
...
onValueChange= {(e) => this.setState({searchText:e.target.value})}

  <button type="button >
       Search
  </button>
```

I want my button to get that value and make the query run when hit submit or press enter. 
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can read the docs on controlled behavior in ReactiveSearch over [here](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/advanced/componentsusage.html#controlled-components). I have also implemented a small example for the above situation you check the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/datasearch-vf2sz).

Answer (score -1):

Just you have to do is ,
set the state (eg. showResult) as true on onClick event of the search button,
And then just add condition to the result list or result card.

Like this:

```
{showResult ? 
 (<ReactiveList
    componentId="results"
    dataField={selected}
    size={15}
    sortBy={sort}
    loader={<ProductLoader />}
    react={{
     and: andQuery
    }}
    onAllData={(results, loadMoreData) => this.getProduct(results)}
   />)
 : ""}
```

Comment: I don't think this should fix this also instead of rending empty `string` we can render `null`. Here is the drawback for this: 

1. No Results displayed when the state is false ( Initial Mount )
2. When will be the state reset after the user has clicked the button?